# CSS: Is there any difference in which property is first in element style?

Tags: css

For example is there any difference between this:

```
element{  
 property1: val1;  
 property2: val2;  
}
```

and this:

```
element{  
 property2: val2;  
 property1: val1;  
}
```

?

*UPDATE* I mean different properties for example `width` and `padding`.

Comment: The only difference is only if both properties affect the same element, and in this case the order would matter.

Comment: You should probably do a little reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: Width and padding are not the same property so their order is irrelevant.  `div { width: 200px; padding: 20px; }` and `div { padding: 20px; width: 200px; }` will produce identical results on the front end, unless the nonstandard box model `border-box` is used, which means padding is subtracted from the width rather than added to it as it is in the default `content-box` box model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if both properties affect the same properties then yes. if you ..

```
.example {
   margin-right: 12px;
   margin: 5px auto;
}
```

the second property cancels out the first property

Comment: only in cases where the properties being defined are the same, yes.  most commonly seen for properties that have shorthand (like `margin` or `padding` or `background` or `border` etc).  So writing `div { margin: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; }` and `div { margin: 20px 20px 10px }` mean the same thing.

Comment: Technically, the properties `margin-right` and `margin` are not the same. The latter is a shorthand that sets the former, along with some other properties. Similar considerations apply to other shorthands, like `font` or `background`.

Answer (score 3):

If the properties are the same, the last one will overwrite the first, and thus be applied.

```
#div1 {
    width:100px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

The properties are different, thus there is no difference. Both properties are applied.

```
#div2 {
    width:100px;
    width:200px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

The `width` property is being applied twice. The last one, `width:200px` will overwrite `width:100px`, and thus be applied. In this example the `width` will be `200px` and the `padding` will be `20px`.

[**See MSN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) for the basics of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If `property1` and `property2` affect the same property, the latter one will overwrite the former.  For example:

```
div {
    background-image: url(images/test.png);
    background: transparent url(images/test2.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

The latter `background` shorthand image `test2.png` will be used, not `test.png` from the first declaration.  This is because when two CSS selectors target the same property of the same element with equal selector specificity, the last one overwrites any earlier declarations.

However, if the two declarations are not for the same property, the order does not matter.

Check out this [great article breaking down CSS specificity rules](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) for more information.  Sounds like you need to get a better grasp on how the cascade works!

Answer (score -1):

I've heard sticklers that argue that CSS properties should be listed in alphabetical order. So there's that, if you want "pretty" code. Otherwise, no difference.